# Checkboxes keep disappearing when adding text in different language

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, plugins, meta-boxes

I have the below code:

```php
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="add-item"><input type="button" id="addCheckboxItem" class="button button-primary" value="<?php _e( 'Add checkbox', 'sha-wreg' ); ?>"></div>
    <table id="checkboxes-table">
        <thead>
            <tr valign="top">
                <th class="detail-name" colspan="2"><?php _e( 'Checkbox label', 'sha-wreg' ); ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ( $checkboxes as $field_id => $field_value ): ?>
                <tr id="detail-<?php echo $field_id; ?>">
                    <td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $sha_wreg_prefix; ?>checkbox_data[<?php echo $field_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo $field_value; ?>" /></td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="remove-item button" onclick="removeRow('<?php echo $field_id; ?>')">-</button></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prefix = '<?php echo $sha_wreg_prefix; ?>'; 
</script>
```

Which outputs as the screenshot below:

[image]

The problem I'm getting is I'm trying to translate the text into French and when I go to save the checkbox the entire row disappears like this:

[image]

This plugin was custom developed for our Wordpress site by another developer who isn't available anymore. Can someone help me with this issue and let me know why the text keeps disappearing as soon as I add another language?

Here is the code for the backend:

```php
    function sha_wreg_add_checkboxes_metabox( $item_data ) {
    global $sha_wreg_module_slug, $sha_wreg_prefix, $sha_wreg_plugin_dir;
    $checkboxes = unserialize( get_post_meta( $item_data->ID, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'checkbox_data', true ) );
    require_once $sha_wreg_plugin_dir . 'admin/templates/checkboxes_metabox.php'; }

    add_action( 'save_post', 'sha_wreg_save_update', 10, 2 );

function sha_wreg_save_update( $item_id, $item_data ) {
    global $sha_wreg_module_slug, $sha_wreg_prefix, $sha_wreg_uploads_dir;

    switch ( $item_data->post_type ) {

        case $sha_wreg_module_slug:
            // Update systems
            if ( isset( $_POST[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'system' ] ) && !empty( $_POST[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'system' ] ) ) {
                //Change status to allocating
                $system_data = get_post_meta( $item_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'system', true );
                $system_name = get_post( $_POST[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'system' ] )->post_title;
                $system_object = array(
                    'id'    => (int)$_POST[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'system' ],
                    'name'  => $system_name
                );

                if ( empty( $system_data ) ) {
                    update_post_meta( $item_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'status', 'Allocated' );
                }
                update_post_meta( $item_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'system', $system_object );
            }

            //Remove empty rows
            foreach ( $_POST[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'detail_data' ] as $k => $v ) {
                if ( empty( $v['name'] ) || ( empty( $v['name'] ) && empty( $v['value'] ) ) ) {
                    unset( $_POST[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'detail_data' ][ $k ] );
                }
            }

            // Update details
            $detail_data = get_post_meta( $item_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'detail_data', true );
            $detail_data = unserialize( $detail_data );
            if ( $detail_data !== $_POST[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'detail_data' ] ) {
                update_post_meta( $item_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'detail_data', serialize( $_POST[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'detail_data' ] ) );
            }

        break;

        case $sha_wreg_module_slug . '_pdfs':
            // Update PDF
            if ( isset( $_FILES[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'pdf_file' ] ) && $_FILES[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'pdf_file' ][ 'error' ] == 0 ) {
                $oldfile = get_post_meta( $item_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'pdf_file', true );
                $uploadfile = sprintf('%s/%s', $sha_wreg_uploads_dir,  $_FILES[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'pdf_file' ]['name'] );

                //Copy PDF
                if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'pdf_file' ]['tmp_name'], $uploadfile ) ) {
                    update_post_meta( $item_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'pdf_file', basename( $uploadfile ) );
                }

                //Remove old PDF
                if ( isset( $oldfile ) && !empty( $oldfile ) ) {
                    if ( file_exists( sprintf( '%s/%s', $sha_wreg_uploads_dir, basename( $oldfile ) ) ) ) {
                        unlink( sprintf( '%s/%s', $sha_wreg_uploads_dir, basename( $oldfile ) ) );
                    }
                }
            }

            // Update checkboxes
            $checkbox_data = get_post_meta( $item_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'checkbox_data', true );
            $checkbox_data = unserialize( $detail_data );
            if ( $checkbox_data !== $_POST[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'checkbox_data' ] ) {
                update_post_meta( $item_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'checkbox_data', serialize( $_POST[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'checkbox_data' ] ) );
            }

            // Update extra data
            $extra_data = get_post_meta( $item_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'extra_data', true );
            $extra_data = unserialize( $extra_data );
            if ( isset( $_POST[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'extra_data' ] ) && ( $extra_data !== $_POST[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'extra_data' ] ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $item_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'extra_data', serialize( $_POST[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'extra_data' ] ) );
            }

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you have shown seems to cover the output part only, that tells us nothing about how/where you are actually storing these values.

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbie and digging through someone else's code to find out this works is a bit tricky. I did think that maybe it was something in the above code that could be causing the problem. I'll paste the backend code as well